# Can I publish a document from one site's document library to another's?

Tags: document-library, publishing, versioning

Here's the scenario:

A development team has a SharePoint site called **Dev**.  There's a document, **foo.txt**, that multiple users are collaborating on.  It lives in a document library.  Users check it out, check it in, etc.

At some point, the document is considered "done" and needs to be published to the rest of the company (QA, support, etc.).  There's a sub-site to **Dev** called **Dev - Published** which contains a single document library, readable by everyone, that contains all of the canonical documents that the dev team wants to share with the company.

Is there a best practice for publishing documents from one site's document library to another's?  Or do we have to manually add/update the file in the sub-site every time we finish a major revision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest option would be to use the "Send To -> Other location" functionality to create a link between the two documents.

When the source document is changed, the user can be prompted to update the various copies in other locations that may exist.

Comment: Agreed. This is the easiest and you can even have the target library be a read-only one to the users (not the one sending it) so there's no chance of them modifying the document (users will ignore the message about this not being the original document).

Answer (score -2):

Probably this is the one you are looking for:

http://www.sptechweb.com/content/article.aspx?ArticleID=35702&page=1